# Is there a good way to do `zfill` in polars?

Tags: python-polars

Is it proper to use `pl.Expr.apply` to throw the python function `zfill` at my data? I'm not looking for a performant solution.

```py
pl.col("column").apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(5))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

And to follow up I'd love to chat about what a good implementation could look like in the discord if you have some insight (assuming one doesn't currently exist).

Comment: I think this is a good candidate new expression: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit: Polars `0.13.43` and later

With version `0.13.43` and later, Polars has a [`str.zfill`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprStringNameSpace.zfill.html#polars.internals.expr.ExprStringNameSpace.zfill) expression to accomplish this.  `str.zfill` will be faster than the answer below and thus `str.zfill` should be preferred.

### Prior to Polars `0.13.43`

From your question, I'm assuming that you are starting with a column of integers.

> lambda x: str(x).zfill(5)

If so, here's one that adheres to pandas rather strictly:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"num": [-10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, None]})

z = 5
df.with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col("num").cast(pl.Utf8).str.lengths() > z)
    .then(pl.col("num").cast(pl.Utf8))
    .otherwise(pl.concat_str([pl.lit("0" * z), pl.col("num").cast(pl.Utf8)]).str.slice(-z))
    .alias("result")
)
```

```
shape: (11, 2)
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ num     ┆ result  │
│ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ str     │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│ -10     ┆ 00-10   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -1      ┆ 000-1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0       ┆ 00000   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       ┆ 00001   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10      ┆ 00010   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100     ┆ 00100   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1000    ┆ 01000   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10000   ┆ 10000   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100000  ┆ 100000  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1000000 ┆ 1000000 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null    ┆ null    │
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comparing the output to pandas:

```py
df.with_column(pl.col('num').cast(pl.Utf8)).get_column('num').to_pandas().str.zfill(z)
```

```
0       00-10
1       000-1
2       00000
3       00001
4       00010
5       00100
6       01000
7       10000
8      100000
9     1000000
10       None
dtype: object
```

If you are starting with strings, then you can simplify the code by getting rid any calls to `cast`.

**Edit:** On a dataset with 550 million records, this took about 50 seconds on my machine.  (Note: this runs single-threaded)

**Edit2:** To shave off some time, you can use the following:

```py
result = df.lazy().with_column(
    pl.col('num').cast(pl.Utf8).alias('tmp')
).with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col("tmp").str.lengths() > z)
    .then(pl.col("tmp"))
    .otherwise(pl.concat_str([pl.lit("0" * z), pl.col("tmp")]).str.slice(-z))
    .alias("result")
).drop('tmp').collect()
```

but it didn't save that much time.